# VS2010 Setup & Deployment - Creating a File Type (Registry Settings)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, registry, setup-deployment

I wanted like to create a file type using Visual Studio 2010's Setup and Deployment project.

**To do this I followed these steps:**

1. Select Setup and Deployment Project in Solution Explorer

   [image: Select Project]
2. Select File Types Editor

   [image: File Types Editor]
3. Right click *File Types on Target Machine* and select *Add File Type*

   [image: Add File Type]
4. Choose a name for the file type.

   [image: Create Name]
5. Go to properties and add an extension and omitting the period.  I.E instead of `.xxx`, entering simply as `xxx`, per the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4fcx9b75(v=vs.100).aspx).

   [image: Choose File Extensions]
6. Choose a command for the file type.  In my case, I want to execute the installed program.

   [image: Select Command]
7. Finally choose an icon for the file type by referring to one already added in the project.

---

Historically, I never used a Setup and Deployment project.  This means I used `.reg` files manually to install the file type association.

What I've noticed is a significant difference in the keys used and would like to compare them and ask what is happening.

### Manual Registry Edits

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.scfg]
@="AutoCAD Script Runner"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner]
@="AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration"
"Version"="1.0.0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner\DefaultIcon]
@="\"<path to icon>\\acad_script.ico\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner\shell\open\command]
@="\"<path to exe>\\AutoCAD Script Runner.exe\" \"%1\""
```

### Setup & Deployment Registry Edits

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.scfg]
@="AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.scfg\AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.scfg\AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration\ShellNew]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration]
@="AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,41,00,50,00,50,00,44,00,41,00,54,00,41,00,25,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,\
  00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,73,00,74,00,\
  61,00,6c,00,6c,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,7b,00,33,00,39,00,37,00,38,00,46,00,37,\
  00,36,00,45,00,2d,00,30,00,36,00,39,00,46,00,2d,00,34,00,46,00,38,00,30,00,\
  2d,00,41,00,33,00,34,00,35,00,2d,00,38,00,41,00,30,00,45,00,37,00,35,00,45,\
  00,33,00,38,00,37,00,46,00,35,00,7d,00,5c,00,5f,00,38,00,35,00,33,00,46,00,\
  36,00,37,00,44,00,35,00,35,00,34,00,46,00,30,00,35,00,34,00,34,00,39,00,34,\
  00,33,00,30,00,45,00,37,00,45,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration\shell\open]
@="&Open"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AutoCAD Script Runner Configuration\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Durr\\AutoCAD Script Runner\\AutoCAD Script Runner.exe\" \"%1\""
"command"=hex(7):40,00,41,00,2a,00,50,00,36,00,48,00,61,00,71,00,56,00,41,00,\
  54,00,65,00,36,00,62,00,27,00,54,00,59,00,5e,00,76,00,77,00,3e,00,24,00,52,\
  00,4a,00,4e,00,46,00,28,00,59,00,70,00,5d,00,3f,00,68,00,61,00,60,00,34,00,\
  2a,00,43,00,40,00,46,00,31,00,21,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00,00,\
  00
```

Both of these registry edits act *apparently the same*, but this cannot be true; both the structure and values are different!

When I view these HEX strings in *RegEdit.exe*, I see the following two values in respective order:

- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Installer{3978F76E-069F-4F80-A345-8A0E75E387F5}_853F67D554F05449430E7E.exe,0
- @A*P6HaqVATe6b'TY^vw>$RJNF(Yp]?ha`4*C@F1! "%1"

I'm led to believe both of these HEX strings (as well as the difference in key-value structure) are necessary for Windows to manage the installation of the application, especially since I see the product code embedded into the first HEX string:

`{3978F76E-069F-4F80-A345-8A0E75E387F5}`

**EDIT:**  It appears the HEX strings are simply the Unicode code points for the *RegEdit.exe* values using little-endian byte ordering.

### Questions

What is the true difference between these two registry edits (manual vs. setup project)?

Why is the structure different and what is the meaning of the HEX strings?

### References

[How to: Add and Delete Document Types and Associated File Extensions in the File Types Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4fcx9b75(v=vs.100).aspx)